# What is the purpose of an unbound socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to networking in Java and in general. I was reading up on sockets and saw the ServerSocket class had a constructor for an unbound socket.

I thought the way socket connections worked was by connecting to specific ports. How could an unbound ServerSocket ever be used then?

thanks.

Comment: Are these the kind of answers you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

An unbound `ServerSocket` cannot be used to accept connections before it is bound.

The no-argument constructor that doesn't yet bind the `ServerSocket` exists so that you can call other methods on the `ServerSocket` before binding it using the `bind` method. There's one method in particular that must be called before binding: `setReuseAddress(boolean on)`. It's Javadoc mentions:

> Enabling SO_REUSEADDR **prior to binding the socket** using
>   {@link #bind(SocketAddress)} allows the socket to be bound even though
>   a previous connection is in a timeout state.

(You could also say that the constructors that *do* perform a bind are merely convenience methods so that you don't have to call the method `bind(SocketAddress)` separately.)

Answer (score 1):

You do need a port. You'd have to call [the bind method](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) on the ServerSocket instance to bind the port to that instance.